# Insert hyphen automatically after every 4 characters in a TextBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

I want to implement some thing that when a user enters 4 characters then a hyphen should be added to the text and then again user enter 4 characters and then again hypen should added automatically in WPF.

Note

**"I want to implement this behavior when user is typing in the text box (not after textbox has lost focus) beacause the later is very easy to implement"**

**Using MVVM model, therefore code behind of Dialog should be empty**

Comment: Try using a MaskedTextBox: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox

Comment: Daniel Hilgarth, Actually i want to do using only plain wpf textbox

Comment: What is the reason for this?

Comment: I have been asked for that by my senior and even if i use MaskTextBox
what mask i have to assign for hyphen patterns

Comment: "Using MVVM model, therefore code behind of Dialog should be empty" That statement is wrong.

Comment: H.B. please go thorugh this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421372/why-to-avoid-the-codebehind-in-wpf-mvvm-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Property Definition :** 
 we should count the characters in the string not including the hyphens
 Caret index cant be set here because `OnPropertyChanged` is not being invoked yet, so the `TextBox.Text` stil contains the old value, and you cant set a value which bigger than the text length:

```
 private string _serial;
 public string Serial
 {
     get { return _serial; }
     set
     {
         if (_serial != value)
         {
             _serial = value;
             int res = 0;
             int hyphensCount = _serial.Count(c => c.Equals('-'));
             Math.DivRem(_serial.Length - hyphensCount, 4, out res);
             if (res == 0)
                 _serial = string.Format("{0}-", _serial);
             OnPropertyChanged("Serial");
         }
     }
 }
```

**Behavior -**
 register to `TextChanged` event and move the caret to the end of text:

```
 public class MoveCaretToEndBehavior: Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_TextChanged);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.CaretIndex = AssociatedObject.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

**TextBox + Behavior**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Serial,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:MoveCaretToEndBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>


</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a property in your viewmodel like the one below. However you'll find that the cursor in the textbox caret doesn't move to the last index and since the caretindex isn't bindable you need to create an attached property to bind to index.

```
        private string _serial;

        public string Serial
        {
            get { return _serial; }
            set
            {
                if (_serial != value)
                {
                    _serial = value;
                    int res = 0;
                    Math.DivRem(_serial.Length, 4, out res);
                    if (res == 0)
                        Serial = string.Format("{0}-", _serial);
                    CaretIndex = _serial.Lenght - 1;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Serial");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the xaml code you need.

```
<Window x:Name="root" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TextBox
        Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Serial, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        local:TextIndexBinder.Index="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Index}"
        />
</Window>
```

Comment: the setter part of property would be called when i would lost focus from textbox that i don't want. i want the effect while user is pressing key

Comment: Notice the UpdateSourceTrigger in the binding. It updates immediately.