# Create wpf project but write code behide like window form?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm starting learning about WPF technology and I have found that the UI of WPF is fixable and better than window form but it takes long time to master it. For example, using command, using data binding, and using MVVM pattern and more. My purpose is that I want to use WPF interface and coding style is the same what I did in window form. So, is it the good idea for starter? and is it difficult to maintenance project or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421372/why-to-avoid-the-codebehind-in-wpf-mvvm-pattern

Answer (score 1):

let me try to explain WPF a bit futher. The primary purpose of WPF was to enable a flexible UI with hardware acceleration so that a developer like us is not limited by the capability of the platform to show their creativity. WPF gives you the power of XAML with strong binding capabilities and with the use of MVVM you can take it to never before levels.

So if you stik to the Win Forms coding practices and standards which are usually hardwired event driven programming, you may find it difficult to find out what WPF bring for you and would be difficult to leverage the true beauty of programming in WPF.

I am a WPF developer, when I started I did exactly the same way and invested much of time doing WPF if old way. I made my decision that WPF is nothing new it is simply a new framework with some enhanced features.

Sooner I begin to see some nice samples on wpf communities and they were awesome piece of work. Then I realized that I am going in a different direction then WPF one.

So I would personally not like you to invest your time in a old way rather you can pick up in WPF kind of style. Work directly on XAML, do bindings for properties and events. Use styles and templates to give the desired look. And far important try to achieve declaratively instead of programatically.

I hope this may help you. Should you need more explanation do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For wpf projects MVVM is the most suitable and maintenance wise it is more convenient. In case of learning purpose and for the small projects we can go ahead with code behind.