# What are potential problems when write business logic code in GUI as MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm, business-logic

Currently, I'm implementing MVVM pattern for a WPF application but not 100% no code behind, sometimes I put some business logic code into GUI and so what are potential problems for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find tons of answers by googling "wpf mvvm vs code behind"

I kinda agree Slugster's answer in [Why to avoid the codebehind in WPF MVVM pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421372/why-to-avoid-the-codebehind-in-wpf-mvvm-pattern)

Putting your business logic into code behind make it hard to write test to your code. I believe this is normally the top 1 reason why people love about MVVM.