# How can I add a Xamarin.Forms XAML file to an FSharp project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

How can I add a Xamarin.Forms XAML file to an FSharp project?

By default, XAML files have C# code-behind.
I tried moving a XAML file with C# code-behind to an F# project.
I then changed the file extension to ".fs".
However, my attempt crashed VS2017.

Comment: it works for me? you have examples in my repo https://github.com/knocte/gwallet/tree/frontend

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

*C# Views & F# ViewModels*

I'm guessing WPF and Xamarin.Forms will see this the same way. You can define all your views in your C# project and have your ViewModel logic in a Portable Class Library (PCL). You can refer your ViewModels directly in your C# project when the View needs its DataContext. This way, it'll behave the same way as it would with a C# ViewModel.

If you'd like a working example of this, I found this that shows exactly what you could do: [MVVM with F#](https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/mvvm-with-f-tutorial/)

*F# MVVM*

If you'd prefer to have an entire application that has F# business logic and XAML in the same project, you can download the following extension: [Windows App in F#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielMohl.FEmptyWindowsAppWPF). By pointing to the FSharp.ViewModule in your directives, you'll be fine.

> The view model which will handle all UI logic. Inherit view model from
>   ViewModelBase

You'll also be able to find a working sample of this kind of thing right [here](http://marisks.net/2015/04/27/f-sharp-xaml-application-mvvm-vs-mvc/)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm actually interested in adding XAML files to my F# project.

Comment: @ScottNimrod please refer to my new update to my answer

Comment: @ScottNimrod What is the current status with the extension?

Answer (score 0):

"Code behind" files don't exist in F# (lack of partial classes), and even in C# many people [recommend keeping those files empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421372/why-to-avoid-the-codebehind-in-wpf-mvvm-pattern).

You can load the Xaml file using `.LoadFromXaml` and access objects using `.FindByName<'t>`. See [Wintellect sample](https://github.com/Wintellect/XamarinSamples/blob/master/FSharpForms/FSharpForms/LoginPage.fs). You need to specify the names as strings and the types so there isn't compile-time safety.

It is not as clean as on WPF, where there is a type provider ([FsXaml](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml)) which gives typed access to the objects. A type provider for Xamarin Forms may appear in future.

I personally prefer to avoid Xaml and do everything in code, where everything is typed and there is no reliance on strings.